# Can't send parameters by ViewBag in JQuery of partial View.

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an MVC3 application with razor syntax. I am working on the partial class for the commenting feature.

My Code is:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddCommentButton').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/Comment/SaveComments',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:
                { 

                'comments': $('#Comment').val(), @ViewBag.EType, @ViewBag.EId
                 },

                   success: function (data) {

                    $("p.p12").append

                   $('.ShowComments').text('Hide Comments');

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to send parameters to the controller from View, using ViewBag, in the above jQuery, but it is not working. How can I do that?

Comment: What values are rendered in your script? Can you show us the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddCommentButton').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveComments", "Comment")',
                data: { 
                    comments: $('#Comment').val(), 
                    etype: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.EType)), 
                    eid: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.EId))
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("p.p12").append(data);
                    $('.ShowComments').text('Hide Comments');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveComments(string comments, string etype, string eid)
{
    ...
}
```

or define a view model:

```
public class SaveCommentViewModel
{
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string EType { get; set; }
    public string EId { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveComments(SaveCommentViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to pass as View model , I want to send as a separate parameter. like this                                       `public JsonResult SaveComments(string comments, string EType , string EId)`

Comment: Not working ... I typed smae as it is ... `comments: $('#Comment').val(), 
                    etype: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.EType)), 
                    eid: @ViewBag.EId                                     It shows warning - '{' expected near Comment and ';' expected near EType. 
`

Comment: Could you update your question and post your actual code because the one in my answer should work. Did you notice that I used `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.EId))` because apparently `ViewBag.EId` is a string value in your case. You haven't provided this information in your question so I assumed it was an integer. I also left a comment in my initial answer stating that if this value is a string you need to encode it.

Comment: Sorry your code works, I have made some silly mistake in my code. ...Thanks Darin for your efforts...